# BASH: Get HTTP link of file

Tags: bash, nginx

Is there a way to get a HTTP link of a file from a script?
For example:
I have a file at:

```
/home/User/video.mp4
```

Next, I would like to get the http link of that file. For example:

```
http://192.168.1.5/video.mp4
```

I currently have nginx installed onto the remote server with a specific directory as the root of the web server.

On the server I have, you can get the server link using this:

```
echo "http://$(whoami).$(hostname -f)/path/to/file"
```

I could get the file link using the command above but this would be an issue with files with spaces in them.

I'm doing this so that I can send the link to Internet Download Manager under windows. So using wget to download files will not work for me.

I'm currently using cygwin to create the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the spaces problem, you can replace them with %20:

```
path="http://$(whoami).$(hostname -f)/path/to/file"
path=${path// /%20}

echo $path
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this does solve the spaces issue, but how about files with square brackets (eg "[ ]"). For example I have a file called "video [720p].mp4". Then this would be converted to "video%20%5b720p%5d.mkv" where "%5b" and "%5d" are the square brackets.

Comment: You're welcome.

The code above just replaces spaces with %20's. To do so, you should repeat the second instruction with different characters:

path=${path//[/%5b}
path=${path//]/%5d}

Comment: Thanks, this should do.